# Facebook Subscribe Event is not showing in the events manager of my app

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-events, facebook-analytics

Bug Report:

- Subscribe event is not showing in the events manager of my App. (All other automatic events are showing.) [ANDROID]

To Reproduce:

1. Try to purchase from Google.
2. Check Test events and/or events inside the Event Manager of your app.
3. Android Subscribe events are not triggering.

Expected Behavior:

All automatic events should trigger, especially the Subscribe event.

As you can see from the screenshot, other automatic events are already triggering, our only problem is the **Subscribe** event which is really important for us.

[image]

Environment:

```
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^10.1.0",
"react-native": "0.66.1",
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. We deal with code here. You'll need to show some.

Comment: The thing is, that is server to server, so I have set up react-native-fbsdk-next correctly since I already get automatic logged events. Which part should I add so that I can make it clearer?

Comment: Well, that may signal that SO isn't the place for your question. Also, it's confusing that you mention Facebook in your title, but Google in your post.

Comment: I will remove the question, but honestly, I put google because the user has to buy from google and check if the subscribe event is on facebook :)